# Angular 15 how to use Router for a generic component in library

Tags: angular

I have created an ***Angular Library*** where I've declared a multi-purpose link component that can be used with href, routerLink or with simple onClick event.

The component has its own module.

Normally when a component uses *RouterLink* & *RouterLinkActive*, I need to implement

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
})
```

or directly

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
})
```

As this is a library I don't know the routes In advance. so how can I implement the Router?

> NOTE: I'm using angular 15

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass required data (such as routerLink, href, etc) in input parameters to your component.

Another one is to pass that data through Angular DI. For example, you can create InjectionToken for every link (same routerLink, href, etc), then inject them into your library's component (probably with Optional decorator) and provide values in external application that uses your library. Or you can create some Service for component, or use single object containing all links, and so on - but all of them just different approaches using DI system.

Pick one of them depending on your architecture and usage scenarios